# Mudar componentes de pasta (Angular.io 7+)

Tags: angular, front-end, angular-cli

Hoje em dia eu tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu projeto Angular7

```
.src
..app
...dash-component
...login-component
...outro-component
```

Existe uma forma de mudar o diretório dos componentes de forma automática, sem que eu precise alterar todas as referências dos componentes no projeto?
Eu queria criar uma estrutura mais ou menos como o exemplo abaixo:

```
.src
..app
...components
....dash-component
....login-component
....outro-component
```

Trocando por miúdos, quero criar uma pasta "components" e agrupar todos os meus componentes dentro dela com o intuito de diminuir a bagunça do projeto.

Eu já sei como usar o angular-cli para criar os components onde eu desejo. Minha dúvida nesse caso é especificamente sobre mover os componentes já existentes.

Comment: Pelo angular-cli hj não é possível, vc pode tentar pesquisar uma forma não oficial.

Comment: @EduardoVargas, tem alguma sugestão sobre isso? Procurei no google, mas não encontrei nada satisfatório.

Comment: Acho que tem que fazer na mão mesmo

Comment: Até já fiz. Usei o VsCode, ele ajuda na hora de alterar as referências... Mas fica aí a dúvida... Se alguém souber responder, eu agradeço.